# Git Extensions - Custom button in ribbon

Tags: git-extensions

In Git Extensions I am actively using different pull and fetch actions. All of them are hidden under context menu - dropdown. It would be super convenient to bring them out in ribbon as separate buttons - is it possible?

I see that it is possible to add custom script that gets triggered on different events.. that might be useful (called from button), but script it-self is NOT what I am looking for.

[image: I want to create a custom button in]

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Maybe look for plugin that might do the job.